# How to change the volume of Video on ReactPixi?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pixi.js

I try to play video using `@pixi/react`.
I can play & stop video below code.
But I don't know how to change the volume of a video.

```
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  ...
  if(...){ //when click "close"
     videoRef.current.destroy(true); // stop video
  }
...
  return(
...
            <Sprite
              image={videourl}
              width={width}
              height={height}
              x={0}
              y={0}
              ref={videoRef}
            />
    )
```